# EasyDropDown.js and links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, href

I'm using [EasyDropDown.js](http://patrickkunka.github.io/easydropdown/) to style a select element -- it essentially creates a nice dropdown menu via jquery.

I'd like to know if it's possible to add a link to one of my select options. Basically, something like this:

```
<select id="db-select" class="dropdown">
            <option value="1"><a href="/apex/RD">1</a></option>
            <option value="2"><a href="/apex/SD">2</a></option>
            <option value="3"><a href="/apex/AD">3</a></option>
        </select>
```

Unfortunately, no documentation seems to be able to provide me the answer of how this can be achieved. When I load the page, the dropdowns have no links.

I know standard HTML does not allow you to add  elements to a select element, but apparently EasyDropDown converts the select into a list. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I read the source of EasyDropDown.js it seems it sets the list contents to

```
option.title
```

so perhaps try to set something like

```
<option title='<a href="/apex/RD">1</a>' value="1">1</option>
```

notice escaping the inner "s
  ^ the above doesnt work as we cant imbed html in the title like this the below section of easydropdown.js can be modified to suit this application by changing .title .val()

```
        $.each(self.options, function(){
            var option = this,
                active = option.selected ? ' class="active"':'';
            self.$dropDown.append('<li'+active+'>'+option.title+'</li>');
        });
```

this is the place to change it.. search easydropdown.js

Comment: Sadly this did not seem to work. I cannot use that as the title as I need to escape the <. Similarly even when I do, it does not appear to append the links to the li element

Comment: @slovak_100 mm thats very unfortunate indeed however if you would like you could perhaps modifiy the library yourself to use .val() instead of .title

Comment: You cannot backslash-escape quotes in HTML attribute values; that's for JS. Single-quote the `title` value and remove the backslashes in it.